# Word 2010 not creating normal.dotm

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to recreate a normal.dotm file because the old one has gotten corrupted.  I've tried deleting the old one, messed with read-only setting in %appdata%\microsoft\template, and removed my workgroup template settings.  But normal.dotm doesn't reappear.  However, there seems to be a normal.dotm template associated with my new Word document.

Do you have any idea a) where word is getting the normal.dotm, and b) how to edit or recreate it?

I'm using Windows 7.   The path to normal.dotm is default: %appdata%\Microsoft\templates.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that Word is using the correct location.  Open Word, go to File > Options > Advanced > File Locations... > User templates > Modify...  The path should be identical to your `%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates`.
2. Your Word shortcut might be [using a switch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565) (e.g. `/a` prevents templates, `/t` overrides the template).  Click Start, then Run, and type `winword` and press enter.  Check if the template has been created.

Comment: See answer above -the path is correct.

Comment: @MaxYaffe I would actually replace the path using copy and paste just in case there's a hard to notice difference.  I also added another possibility.